# Are every computers on a router connected to VPN by default?

Tags: vpn

I have a Windows desktop, Macbook and PS3 all connected to my home router and working properly.  If I use my Macbook to connect to the office VPN, will my Windows desktop and PS3 also be on the VPN by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - the VPN is initiated from the device you start it on, and affects only that device.

However, if your router could VPN, then yes - everything on the network would be on the VPN.

Comment: Or if the Macbook was set to forward packets to and from the VPN.

Comment: @grawity - true.. but then the MacBook is acting as a router for the network, no?

Comment: I believe it is possible to only act as a router for one subnet. Even if not, all OSes support separate gateways for specific subnets *in addition to* the default gateway. Either way, it would only require 1) enabling forwarding, 2) adding routes to the VPN through MacBook on all other computers. (I actually do have a virtual machine that provides connectivity to a VPN to all my LAN -- using RIP for routing.)

Comment: @grawity - good point that I hadn't thought of :)